# Server Error ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: next.js

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';

class CustomDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
    return { ...initialProps };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en-US">
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default CustomDocument;
```

I was attempted to edit this landing page and entered

```
npm run dev
```

however, the following error has displayed.

```
Server Error
ReferenceError: window is not defined

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
```

```
pages\_document.tsx (91:33) @ Function.getInitialProps

  89 |     }
  90 | 
> 91 |     const { html, head } = await ctx.renderPage({ enhanceApp })
     |                                 ^
  92 |     const styles = [...flush()]
  93 |     return { html, head, styles }
  94 |   }
```

It also says the following error.

```
Call Stack
Function.getInitialProps
```

Anyone can help to resolve this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the code for the page you're trying to render? You're most likely trying to access the `window` object during server-side rendering. Make sure to run any code that depends on `window` on the client-side only, e.g., inside a `useEffect`.

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is connected to styled component's SSR you can find more about that [here](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/3444)